# Display array of JSON results in HTML grouped by the array name

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a global search feature (where the search bar in the top navigation searches the entire website) that pulls from different indexes and displays the results in the dropdown list. Below I've put an example JSON response. This works fine and dandy, but I've had difficulties refactoring it to group results by the array header, i.e `"Customers"`. Currently, all of the results are outputted into a single list.

How can I break up the `ul`, and output results to include an `h3` tag with the name of the array? I can grab it using `getOwnPropertyNames` but cleaning up the `forEach` loops is a bit unclear.

Example JSON payload

```
{ 
  "customers": [
    { "title": "Customer 1", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { "title": "Customer 2", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { "title": "Customer 3", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { "title": "Customer 4", url: "...", template: "..." },
  ],
  "reservations": [
    { "title": "Reservation 1", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { "title": "Reservation 2", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { "title": "Reservation 3", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { "title": "Reservation 4", url: "...", template: "..." },
  ],
  "settings": [
    { "title": "Help Docs", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { "title": "My Dashboard", url: "...", template: "..." }
  ]
}
```

Every time you type into this box, we use the fetch API to query results against `../search/autocomplete?query=`, and combine those results into a JSON object that gets returned to the browser, and then displayed to users.

```
fetch(`${this.data.get("url")}${this.queryInputTarget.value}`)
      .then(data=> {
        return data.json();
      })
      .then(results=> {
        let resultsHTML = ""

        results.customers.forEach((resultJSON) => {
          resultsHTML += resultJSON.template
        })

        results.reservations.forEach((resultJSON) => {
          resultsHTML += resultJSON.template
        })

        results.settings.forEach((resultJSON) => {
          resultsHTML += resultJSON.template
        })

        this.searchResultsListTarget.innerHTML = resultsHTML
      })

      // console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(results));
      // ["customers", "reservations", "settings"]
```

The output gets inserted after `<ul data-target="search.searchResultsList">`. For simplicity I'm showing the `title` below, but the above function returns the `template` from each JSON object.

```
<div class="search-results-box scrollable" data-target="search.searchResults">
  <ul data-target="search.searchResultsList">
    <li aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="0">Customer 1</li>
    <li aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="0">Customer 2</li>
    <li aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="0">Customer 3</li>
    <li aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="0">Customer 4</li>
    <li aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="0">Reservation 1</li>
    <li aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="0">Reservation 2</li>
    <li aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="0">Reservation 3</li>
    <li aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="0">Reservation 4</li>
    <li aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="0">Help Docs</li>
    <li aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="0">My Dashboard</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `let resultsHTML = ""
resultsHTML += '<li> Customers <ul>';
        results.customers.forEach((resultJSON) => {
          resultsHTML += resultJSON.template
        }) resultsHTML += '</ul></li>';` This will wrap the customers list in another UL making it look like you have grouped it

Comment: I'd want the function to iterate and include the name of _each_ array in the response, i.e `customers`, `reservations`, `settings` and this doesn't full account for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You'll need to process your object one way or another -- be it using `forEach`, `map` or a good old `for loop`.

```js
const res = {
  customers: [
    { title: "Customer 1", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { title: "Customer 2", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { title: "Customer 3", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { title: "Customer 4", url: "...", template: "..." }
  ],
  reservations: [
    { title: "Reservation 1", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { title: "Reservation 2", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { title: "Reservation 3", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { title: "Reservation 4", url: "...", template: "..." }
  ],
  settings: [
    { title: "Help Docs", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { title: "My Dashboard", url: "...", template: "..." }
  ]
};

const generateListItem = (value, text, is_disabled = false) =>
  `<li aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="0" data-value="${value}" ${
    is_disabled ? "disabled" : ""
  }>${text}</li>`;

const renderUL = (html_text) => {
  document.querySelector(
    '[data-target="search.searchResultsList"]'
  ).innerHTML = html_text;
};

const processResults = (results) => {
  let html_text = "";

  const categories = results && Object.keys(results);

  if (categories && categories.length) {
    categories.map((category) => {
      html_text += `<h3>${category}</h3>`;
      results[category].map((item) => {
        html_text += generateListItem(JSON.stringify(item), item.title, false);
      });
    });
    renderUL(html_text);
    return;
  }

  // handle empty results here...
};

processResults(res);
```

```html
<ul data-target="search.searchResultsList"></ul>
```

### Note that there are [templating engines](https://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/) that save you lots of time in situations like yours.

You still need to do some pre-processing but it's much more scalable than appending raw html strings to one another.

```js
const res = {
  customers: [
    { title: "Customer 1", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { title: "Customer 2", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { title: "Customer 3", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { title: "Customer 4", url: "...", template: "..." }
  ],
  reservations: [
    { title: "Reservation 1", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { title: "Reservation 2", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { title: "Reservation 3", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { title: "Reservation 4", url: "...", template: "..." }
  ],
  settings: [
    { title: "Help Docs", url: "...", template: "..." },
    { title: "My Dashboard", url: "...", template: "..." }
  ]
};

const renderUL = (ul_content) => {
  document.querySelector(
    '[data-target="search.searchResultsList"]'
  ).innerHTML = Hogan.compile(
    document.querySelector("#searchResultsListTemplate").textContent
  ).render({ ul_content: ul_content });
};

const processResults = (results) => {
  const categories = results && Object.keys(results);

  if (categories && categories.length) {
    const to_render = [];

    categories.map((category) => {
      to_render.push({
        category,
        items: results[category].map((item) => {
          return {
            title: item.title,
            stringified_item: JSON.stringify(item)
          };
        })
      });
    });

    renderUL(to_render);
    return;
  }

  // handle empty results here...
};

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
   processResults(res);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hogan.js/3.0.2/hogan.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/template" id="searchResultsListTemplate">
{{#ul_content}}
  <h3>{{category}}</h3>
  {{#items}}
    <li aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="0" data-item="{{stringified_item}}">{{title}}</li>
  {{/items}}
{{/ul_content}}
</script>

<ul data-target="search.searchResultsList"></ul>
```

Comment: Hey @jzzfs - both of your suggestions are great. I have yet to try the latter, but the way you've separated `generateListItem` and `renderUL` is doing the job. Stay tuned for the bounty in the coming 24 hours :party_emoji: